# Calculated field in a Dextop C# model

Tags: c#, extjs4

What is the best way to create a calculated field in a Dextop C# model that does the following:

Creates the value for the FullName field based both the FirstName and LastName fields, similar to the following in ExtJs:

```
function fullName(v, record){
return record.name.last + ', ' + record.name.first;
}

Ext.define('Contact', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
{name: 'fullname', convert: fullName},
{name: 'firstname', mapping: 'name.first'},
{name: 'lastname', mapping: 'name.last'}
]
});
```

Updates the FullName field in realtime as the user is typing in either the FirstName or LastName fields on the form.

C# model code:

```
[DextopModel] 
[DextopGrid] 
[DextopForm] 
class MyModel 
{ 

[DextopModelId] 
[DextopGridColumn(width = 50, readOnly=true)]
public int Id { get; set; } 

[DextopFormField(anchor = "0", allowBlank = false, labelAlign = "top")]
[DextopGridColumn()]
public String FirstName { get; set; }

[DextopFormField(anchor = "0", allowBlank = false, labelAlign = "top")]
[DextopGridColumn()]
public String LastName { get; set; }

[DextopFormField(anchor="0", readOnly=true, labelAlign = "top")] 
[DextopGridColumn(flex=1)] 
public String FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is very simple. Dextop supports calculated columns on the server side. Change the FullName property like in the sample below.

```
[DextopFormField(anchor="0", readOnly=true, labelAlign = "top")] 
[DextopGridColumn(flex=1)]    
public String FullName { get { return String.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); } }
```

As an alternative you can use DextopModelField attribute to specify convert function which will be generated in the model.